# Getting Null value from JSP to Servlet in second Declaration

Tags: java, jsp

I have a problem in declaration of `int dept_id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("dept_id"));` It always get java.lang.NumberFormatException: null. but the first declaration of int emp_id it is working but for dept_id it always get null value.

Here is my Servlet

```
public UserController() {
    super();
    udao = new UserDao();
    ddao = new DepartmentDao();

}

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String forward="";
    String action = request.getParameter("action");

        forward = INSERT_OR_EDIT;
        int emp_id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("emp_id"));
        int dept_id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("dept_id"));


        User user = udao.GetUser(emp_id);
        User user2 = ddao.GetHub(dept_id);

        request.setAttribute("user", user);
        request.setAttribute("user2", user2);



    RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(forward);
    view.forward(request, response);
}
```

JSP

```
<fieldset>
        <legend id="myLegend">User</legend>
<!--        <label for="emp_id">
                Employee ID :
                </label> -->
        <input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="emp_id" style="display:none"
                    value="<c:out value="${user.emp_id}"  />" />


        <label for="serial_number">Serial Number :</label>
                <input type="text" name="serial_number" placeholder="
                    value="<c:out value="${user.serial_number}" />" /><br /><br /> 


            <!--        <label for="dept_id">
                Department ID :
                </label> -->
        <input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="emp_id" style="display:none"
                    value="<c:out value="${user2.dept_id}"  />" />


                <label>Hub :</label>
                <input type="text" name="department_name" 
                    value="<c:out value="${user2.dept_name}" />" /><br /><br /> 



    </fieldset>
```

Comment: You have named `emp_id` twice in `<input type="text">`. One is expected to be `dept_id`. Hence, there is no element with the name `dept_id` on your form.

Comment: You probably copied the emp_id input code and forgot to rename it to dept_id.

Answer (score 1):

The name for your dept_id is emp_id. It should look like:

```
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="dept_id" style="display:none"
                value="<c:out value="${user2.dept_id}"  />" />
```

I think you just overlooked this!

Comment: I already changed it but it still the same. Its still pointing this  `int dept_id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("dept_id"));`